# bootstrap 3: images of same height displaying at different heights

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I've designed an image grid using bootstrap using images that are either 360px square, or 360px high by 720px wide. For some reason, the wide images display taller in the row. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is [the code in bootply](http://www.bootply.com/f1RCuKvvIH)

Thanks!

Comment: it appears to be scaling the images down a bit, based on the sample

Answer (score 0):

The images won't display at the same height just because they're the same physical height because they are scaling with your layout. And the padding in each column and elements in the columns reduces the horizontal space available for the images, and when the horizontal size changes, the vertical size will change, too (to scale the image properly).

Look at how the left/wide image is only in a single column, but the 2 images on the right are in 2 columns. There is more padding in the 2 images on the right than on the left (twice as much padding, since there are twice as many images). That's scaling the height of each to be shorter than the image on the left.

I removed the padding from the `.col-*` classes and `.thumbnail` to show that if you remove those, the images line up.

http://www.bootply.com/KacXrRCbYH

You would fix this any number of ways, but I think that needs to be up to you as to what's going to work best for your layout. The easiest way is probably just to change the height of the image on the left to account for that padding. 720x341 seems to be the resolution that works there.

http://www.bootply.com/T4F3fdgNyf

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Although adjusting the image height seems hackey, it is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: @Martin what's hacky about it? You have to offset the space somehow. It isn't hacky, it's math :)

Comment: Good point. My thought was it might not line up perfectly when resizing the window but it seems fine. Thanks again!